# Postgres Upgrading Errors due to table not existing

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, psql

I am trying to do an upgrade from Postgres 9.6 to 12, I have done this in the past but in this instance I am having difficulty.

When running the pg_upgrade command followed by the parameters:

```
/usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_upgrade --old-bindir /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin --new-bindir /usr/pgsql-12/bin --old-datadir /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data --new-datadir /var/lib/pgsql/12/data --link
```

On doing a check prior nothing comes up as an issue, when i remove the check flag and run I get the following:

```
command: "/usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_dump" --host /var/lib/pgsql --port 50432 --username postgres --schema-only --quote-all-identifiers --binary-upgrade --format=custom  --file="pg_upgrade_dump_2554867.custom" 'dbname=titan' >> "pg_upgrade_dump_2554867.log" 2>&1
pg_dump: error: query failed: ERROR:  relation "staging.stg_fct_game_stats" does not exist
pg_dump: error: query was: LOCK TABLE "staging"."stg_fct_game_stats" IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

What is odd about this is when I look at the tables in this schema after setting my search_path. I run \dt and cannot see this table in that schema.

I then run:

```
SELECT n.nspname AS schemaname, c.relname, c.relkind
FROM   pg_class c
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE  relname like '%stg_fct_game_stats';
```

This returns a result:

```
schemaname  relname relkind
staging stg_fct_game_stats  r
```

If I remove the like and have it as = 'stg_fct_game_stats' it would not appear.

I suspect there is some corruption but I cannot even drop the table as it cannot see this table?

Any ideas, I am happy to remove the table but errors:

```
 DROP TABLE staging.stg_fct_game_stats;
ERROR:  table "stg_fct_game_stats" does not exist
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `select relname, encode(relname::bytea, 'hex') from pg_class where relname like '%stg_fct_game_stats';` please share the result of this query.

Comment: @Melkij returns nothing....

Comment: @Melkij If I remove the relname, encode(relname::bytea, 'hex')  and just do a select * on the pg_class table it returns that relname.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the index on `(relname, relnamespace)` in `pg_catalog.pg_class` is in a corrupt state.
That would explain why a sequential scan (with the LIKE clause) finds an entry that an index-based lookup can't find.

Generally the advice in that situation is to `REINDEX pg_catalog.pg_class;`

If the problem is limited to that particular table, that might be sufficient, at least to  bring the database to a state where it can be dumped.

Make sure to not change the locales of your operating system without reindexing the text columns in your databases (check out https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Locale_data_changes for why). In recent versions of Postgres, the columns of type `name` in `pg_catalog` are not affected by this, but I'm not sure for version 9.6

Comment: Not the OP. I gave your solution a try, but it didn't work. I reindexed *everything*. No go. Must be something else. Pg_dump, etc works, so it's just ... odd